# How can I efficiently extract repeated elements in a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, count, element

I have an array like [1,1,1,2,4,6,3,3] and I would like to get the list of repeated elements, in this case [1,3].  I wrote this:

```
my_array.select{|obj|my_array.count(obj)>1}.uniq
```

But it is tragically inefficient (o(n²)).  Do you have a better idea?  If possible concise.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspired by Ilya Haykinson's answer:

```
def repeated(array)
  counts = Hash.new(0)
  array.each{|val|counts[val]+=1}
  counts.reject{|val,count|count==1}.keys
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that's cleaner than mine.  Just for fun, here's that method all on one line, assuming availability of the "tap" method from Ruby >= 1.8.7.
array.inject(Hash.new(0)){|counts,val|counts.tap{|c|c[val]+=1}}.reject{|val,count|count==1}.keys

I think yours is more readable, though. :)

Comment: I really, really like this solution, and I like it because it is the most readable/understandable one among all the O(n) solutions. Here's a one-liner modification, just for fun: `array.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, i| h[i] += 1; h }.reject { |v, c| c == 1 }.keys`

Comment: Thanks! Amazing... I was suffering with `detect`, `find_all`, etc

Comment: This is ok but anyone who thinks it's the best answer needs to get familiar with `Set.new`. It uses a hash under hood and is great when you need the O(1) hash key access but with the simplicity of an array. Plus it aides readability as all the logic shrinks to the beautifully obvious `dups.add(val) if seen_already.include?(val)`

Answer (score 6):

Using Ruby's [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html) library:

```
require 'set'

ary = [1,1,1,2,4,6,3,3]
dups = Set.new
test_set = Set.new
ary.each {|val| dups.add(val) unless test_set.add?(val)}
dups.to_a # [1, 3]
```

I believe this should be O(n), because Set#add and Set#add? are constant-time operations, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this? It will run in O(n).

```
a = [1,1,1,2,4,6,3,3]
b = {}
a.each { |v| if b.has_key? v then b[v] = b[v]+1 else b[v]=1 end }
b.reject { |k,v| if v > 1 then false else true end }.keys
```

Comment: I like the idea.  You could beautify the last line like this: b.reject{|k,v| v==1}.keys

Comment: Also, you could use b=Hash.new(0), and then you would have a simpler 3rd line: a.each{|v|b[v]+=1}

Answer (score 3):

A O(n) solution (change `<< x` to `+ [x]` and `update` to `merge` to make it purely functional):

```
rs = xs.inject([[], {}]) do |(out, seen), x| 
  [(seen[x] == 1 ? (out << x) : out), seen.update(x => (seen[x] || 0)+1)]
end[0]
```

A much simpler yet less space-efficient approach:

```
rs = xs.group_by { |x| x }.select { |y, ys| ys.size > 1 }.keys
```

The same idea avoiding the intermediate hash using a "list-comprehension":

```
rs = xs.group_by { |x| x }.map { |y, ys| y if ys.size > 1 }.compact
```

Comment: There's a problem with this solution. See `xs = [1,1,1]`.

Comment: Wouldn't group_by be a better fit?

Comment: @Andrew. I thought there was already a solution using group_by, but it seems it was in the other question. I'll add it. Now that Ruby has ordered hashes we can preserve the order of the original enumerable. However, it's less space efficient than a custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `inject`

```
[1,1,1,2,4,6,3,3].inject({}){ |ele, n| ele[n] = nil; ele }.keys 
# => [1, 2, 4, 6, 3]
```

#### EXPLANATION:

`ele` hash it's initialled to `{}`, each iteration a key with the number `n` and `nil` value is added to the `ele` hash. At the end `ele` is returned as:

```
{1=>nil, 2=>nil, 4=>nil, 6=>nil, 3=>nil}
```

We only want the keys, so `.keys` ends the job.

Comment: Thanks but I only wanted *repeated* elements, as indicated in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas: you'd have to figure out the correct library data structures:

> **1** Sort the array O(nlogn), then run through the array
>
> **2** Create a set, search for the current array element in the set and if not found, insert and proceed for all the elements -- O(nlogn) again.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of counting how many times a unique element appears in array. 
It may be really inefficient just like the original suggestion but it was fun looking at the problem.
I didn't do any benchmarks on larger arrays so this is just an excercise.

```
a = [1,1,1,2,4,6,3,3]

dupes = []
a.uniq.each do |u|
  c = a.find_all {|e| e == u}.size
  dupes << [u, c] unless c == 1
end

puts dupes.inspect

# dupes = [[1, 3], [3, 2]]
# 1 appears 3 times
# 3 appears twice


# to extract just the elment a bit cleaner
dupes = a.uniq.select do |u|
  a.find_all {|e| e == u}.size != 1
end
puts dupes.inspect
# returns [1,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if the duplicated entries are always consecutive, as in your example; otherwise you would have to sort first.  each_cons examines a rolling window of the specified size.

```
require 'set'

my_array = [1,1,1,2,4,6,3,3]
dups = Set.new
my_array.each_cons(2) {|a,b| dups.add(a) if (a == b)}
p dups.to_a
```