# Remove duplicate elements from array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, duplicates

I have a Ruby array which contains duplicate elements.

```
array = [1,2,2,1,4,4,5,6,7,8,5,6]
```

How can I remove all the duplicate elements from this array while retaining all unique elements without using for-loops and iteration?

Answer (score 812, accepted):

```
array = array.uniq
```

[`uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq) removes all duplicate elements and retains all unique elements in the array.

This is one of many beauties of the Ruby language.

Comment: no, the uniq! method will return nil if the array had been unique yet
Ex: a = [1,2,3,4]
    a.uniq -> [1,2,3,4]
   but
    a.uniq! -> nil

Comment: i wouldn't really see this as a beauty of the ruby language...it's just the beauty of the ruby standard library?

don't get me wrong, there are a lot of beautiful things about the language.

Comment: write the same in Objective-C, Javascript and PHP. Then tell us that Ruby isn't a beautiful language!

Comment: @AdamWaite For example in php you cant make this in easy way: "If a block is given, it will use the return value of the block for comparison." And ruby syntax of array.uniq is more short, clear and coincise than php -> array_unique(array).  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq

Comment: @AdamWaite: yes ruby is; but its again "uniq" not "unique" :'|, I always/still fight with so little things with ruby

Comment: This also works for complex types:
 `[{how:  "are"}, {u:"doing"}, {how: "are"}].uniq => [{:how=>"are"}, {:u=>"doing"}]`

Comment: Also, `.uniq!` is a mutator. In case you wanted to preserve your `array`

Comment: about what @duykhoa says, the uniq! method returns nil, but you usually don't care about the return of a `.uniq!` it does the work on the object itself

Comment: it should also be mentioned that a block can be given if the uniqueness constraint is more complex; for instance, you could do `array.uniq { |i| i % 3 }` to get the unique values modulo 3 (1, 2, 6)

Answer (score 91):

You can  return the intersection.

```
a = [1,1,2,3]
a & a
```

This will also delete duplicates.

Comment: Functionally, this answer is correct, but I think this is markedly less readable than just using uniq.

Comment: I was just putting it here so whoever visits this page will see other ways of doing it as well, I was not trying to say it is better in any way.

Comment: The reason this works is because when using set operations, the resulting array is treated as a set, which is a data structure that usually has no repeat values. Using `a | a` (union) would do the same trick.

Answer (score 59):

You can remove the duplicate elements with the uniq method:

```
array.uniq  # => [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

What might also be useful to know is that `uniq` takes a block, so if you have a have an array of keys:

```
["bucket1:file1", "bucket2:file1", "bucket3:file2", "bucket4:file2"]
```

and you want to know what the unique files are, you can find it out with:

```
a.uniq { |f| f[/\d+$/] }.map { |p| p.split(':').last }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this. The block is used if you need your own comparison function -- in your example, sending `uniq` to that array without a block would return the same value as it does with your block.

Answer (score 22):

If someone was looking for a way to remove all instances of repeated values, see "[How can I efficiently extract repeated elements in a Ruby array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786879/how-can-i-efficiently-extract-repeated-elements-in-a-ruby-array)".

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3]
counts = Hash.new(0)
a.each { |v| counts[v] += 1 }
p counts.select { |v, count| count == 1 }.keys # [1, 3]
```

Comment: Or could simply do 

    `a = [1, 2, 2, 3]
    a.find_all { |x| a.count(x) == 1 } # [1, 3]`

Comment: The linked question is not the same; It's asking how to find duplicated values and return them. The OP wants to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 20):

Just another alternative if anyone cares.

You can also use the `to_set` method of an array which converts the Array into a Set and by definition, set elements are unique.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6].to_set => [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: If you care about memory, `to_set` will allocate 4 objects, while `uniq` allocates one.

Comment: Yeah, I set .uniq vs .to_set in a benchmark test and got 32 ms for .to_set and 7 ms for .uniq. In conclusion, it's way less programmatically expensive to use .uniq

Answer (score 13):

The simplest ways for me are these ones:

```rb
array = [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

#### `Array#to_set`

```rb
array.to_set.to_a

# [1, 2, 3]
```

#### `Array#uniq`

```rb
array.uniq

# [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to provide some insight:

```
require 'fruity'
require 'set'

array = [1,2,2,1,4,4,5,6,7,8,5,6] * 1_000

def mithun_sasidharan(ary)
  ary.uniq
end

def jaredsmith(ary)
  ary & ary
end

def lri(ary)
  counts = Hash.new(0)
  ary.each { |v| counts[v] += 1 }
  counts.select { |v, count| count == 1 }.keys 
end

def finks(ary)
  ary.to_set
end

def santosh_mohanty(ary)
    result = ary.reject.with_index do |ele,index|
      res = (ary[index+1] ^ ele)
      res == 0
    end
end

SHORT_ARRAY = [1,1,2,2,3,1]
mithun_sasidharan(SHORT_ARRAY) # => [1, 2, 3]
jaredsmith(SHORT_ARRAY) # => [1, 2, 3]
lri(SHORT_ARRAY) # => [3]
finks(SHORT_ARRAY) # => #<Set: {1, 2, 3}>
santosh_mohanty(SHORT_ARRAY) # => [1, 2, 3, 1]

puts 'Ruby v%s' % RUBY_VERSION

compare do
  _mithun_sasidharan { mithun_sasidharan(array) }
  _jaredsmith { jaredsmith(array) }
  _lri { lri(array) }
  _finks { finks(array) }
  _santosh_mohanty { santosh_mohanty(array) }
end
```

Which, when run, results in:

```
# >> Ruby v2.7.1
# >> Running each test 16 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> _mithun_sasidharan is faster than _jaredsmith by 2x ± 0.1
# >> _jaredsmith is faster than _santosh_mohanty by 4x ± 0.1 (results differ: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] vs [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, ...
# >> _santosh_mohanty is similar to _lri (results differ: [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, ...
# >> _lri is similar to _finks (results differ: [] vs #<Set: {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}>)
```

Note: these returned bad results:

- `lri(SHORT_ARRAY) # => [3]`
- `finks(SHORT_ARRAY) # => #<Set: {1, 2, 3}>`
- `santosh_mohanty(SHORT_ARRAY) # => [1, 2, 3, 1]`

Answer (score -4):

Try using the XOR operator, without using built-in functions:

```
a = [3,2,3,2,3,5,6,7].sort!

result = a.reject.with_index do |ele,index|
  res = (a[index+1] ^ ele)
  res == 0
end

print result
```

With built-in functions:

```
a = [3,2,3,2,3,5,6,7]

a.uniq
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted and I know next to nothing about Ruby, but isn't `.sort!` also an inbuilt function?