# how to get repeated elements from ruby array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

suppose I have an array [1,2,3,1,5,2].
Here 1 and 2 are the repeated elements. I want to get a new array [1,2].

How do I do that in ruby ??

Comment: @mihai, thanks, voted to close, now you can safely remove your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
arr = [1,2,3,1,5,2]
arr.group_by {|e| e}.map { |e| e[0] if e[1][1]}.compact
```

Pretty ugly... but does the job without an n+1 problem.

Comment: Also, perhaps clearer `arr.group_by { |v| v }.select { |k, v| v.count > 1 }.keys`

Comment: I actually started with that exact line, but took the .count out to do one less operation for every element.

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [1,2,3,1,5,2]
arr.select { |x| arr.count(x) > 1 } .uniq
```

A longer solution using `reduce` should be quicker.

```
arr.reduce [{}, []] do |(seen, out), cur|
  case seen[cur]
    when :seen then
      [seen.merge({cur => :added}), out << cur]
    when :added then
      [seen, out]
    else
     [seen.merge({cur => :seen}), out]
  end
end.last
```

Comment: I wrote something similar in the duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8459032/188031. But I see some problems here:  1) you are using an array object to test inclussion, which is O(n), a hash or set would be more suitable. 2) you can safely remove the `uniq`. 3) Use arguments expansion instead of acc[0]/acc[1].

Comment: @tokland, thanks for the comment. 1) I've switched to `Hash`. 2) No, unfortunately not. See `[1,1,1]`. 3) Good point!

Comment: After the last change `uniq` isn't necessary any longer.

Comment: you are right! now I have to check my solution.