# Get two (or more) common values from a string number in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

```
a = [1, 2, 56, 3, 56, 7, 7, 7, 56, 40, 40, 40]
a.group_by do |e|                                            
    e                                                               
end.values.max_by(&:size).first
```

This return `56` but how we do to return all the common values like: `[56,7,40]`

We can create a hash with all repetitions and after with select get the numbers with the max repetitions value. But maybe there are a easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.select { |e| a.count(e) > 1 }.uniq
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `group_by`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8458995/644810

Comment: `group_by` is superfluous. I was the other person who voted to close :)